# UWP : How to set the main icon

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, icons, win-universal-app

I actually build my first universal app on windows 10, and I don't konw to change the main icon of the application (icon visible on taskbar) ?

I've setted icon in visual assets with no visible change.
Can you help me ?

Thanks
Mickaël

Comment: It should be the 24px one in the visual assets.

Comment: I have try to clear all assets and set them again, and it is ok.
But after that, I try to update again the main icon, I did the same operation and this time, the icon not update... really strange...

Comment: I highly recommend UWP Visual Assets Generator. You can install it as an add-on in VS. It will generate any/all image assets for you from a single image AND add them to your project in the correct folders AND update your project including the manifest. Worked amazing for me on the first try

Answer (score 9):

You must set the 24x24 px image under Assets\Square44x44Logo.png

Answer (score 4):

I've had similar problems, then [this tool](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/02/15/uwp-tile-generator-extension-for-visual-studio/#V6vhJZWG7YxV42c0.97) solved it for me.

Seems like the problem was that I also needed to have some of those Square44x44Logo.targetsize-xx.png files, because the problem happened again after I removed those (autogenerated) files.

Comment: default VS 2017 generate already generates those and sets under the manifest but Main Icon is still not updating.